# What is meaning of 'NotFoundError: No algorithm worked!'?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

a time ago, I write a CNN code that detects cats and dogs. The data is taken from Kaggle and the CNN code is succesfully worked. And before that to make learning faster, I installed Nvidia Cuda. Now I found a new task from Kaggle (https://www.kaggle.com/paultimothymooney/chest-xray-pneumonia). I have written CNN code again. But I get an error I have never seen.

Code:

```
import os
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, Dense, Flatten
from keras import optimizers
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator


def data():
    dataset = 'C:/Users/Lenovo/Desktop/chest_xray/'
    train = os.path.join(dataset, 'train')
    test = os.path.join(dataset, 'test')
    validation = os.path.join(dataset, 'val')
    train_data = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1. / 255)
    test_data = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1. / 255)

    train_generator = train_data.flow_from_directory(
        train,
        target_size=(1000, 1000),
        batch_size=16,
        class_mode='binary')

    validation_generator = test_data.flow_from_directory(
        validation,
        target_size=(1000, 1000),
        batch_size=16,
        class_mode='binary')

    test_generator = test_data.flow_from_directory(
        test,
        target_size=(1000, 1000),
        batch_size=16,
        class_mode='binary')

    for data_batch, labels_batch in train_generator:
        print('data batch shape:', data_batch.shape)
        print('label batch shape:', labels_batch.shape)
        break
    return validation_generator, test_generator, train_generator


def detector():
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Conv2D(32, (4, 4), activation='relu', input_shape=(1000, 1000, 1)))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D((3, 3)))
    model.add(Conv2D(64, (4, 4), activation='relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D((3, 3)))
    model.add(Conv2D(64, (4, 4), activation='relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D((3, 3)))
    model.add(Conv2D(128, (4, 4), activation='relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D((3, 3)))
    model.add(Conv2D(128, (4, 4), activation='relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D((3, 3)))
    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(256, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(256, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
    model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
                  optimizer=optimizers.RMSprop(lr=1e-4))
    model.summary()
    return model


validation_, test_, train_ = data()
model_ = detector()

history = model_.fit_generator(
    train_,
    steps_per_epoch=100,
    epochs=30,
    validation_data=validation_,
    validation_steps=50)
```

Output:

```
C:\Users\Lenovo\anaconda3\python.exe "C:/Users/Lenovo/PycharmProjects/AI/1- Text.py"
2020-10-30 12:03:20.802426: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_101.dll
Found 5216 images belonging to 2 classes.
Found 16 images belonging to 2 classes.
Found 624 images belonging to 2 classes.
data batch shape: (16, 1000, 1000, 3)
label batch shape: (16,)
2020-10-30 12:03:24.063892: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library nvcuda.dll
2020-10-30 12:03:25.009097: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1716] Found device 0 with properties: 
pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0 name: GeForce GTX 1050 Ti computeCapability: 6.1
coreClock: 1.62GHz coreCount: 6 deviceMemorySize: 4.00GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 104.43GiB/s
2020-10-30 12:03:25.009744: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_101.dll
2020-10-30 12:03:25.017137: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library cublas64_10.dll
2020-10-30 12:03:25.022144: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library cufft64_10.dll
2020-10-30 12:03:25.024962: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library curand64_10.dll
2020-10-30 12:03:25.030998: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library cusolver64_10.dll
2020-10-30 12:03:25.034229: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library cusparse64_10.dll
2020-10-30 12:03:25.052663: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library cudnn64_7.dll
2020-10-30 12:03:25.053092: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1858] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2020-10-30 12:03:25.053825: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN)to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  AVX2
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
2020-10-30 12:03:25.063634: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:168] XLA service 0x1dafce31430 initialized for platform Host (this does not guarantee that XLA will be used). Devices:
2020-10-30 12:03:25.064420: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:176]   StreamExecutor device (0): Host, Default Version
2020-10-30 12:03:25.065036: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1716] Found device 0 with properties: 
pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0 name: GeForce GTX 1050 Ti computeCapability: 6.1
coreClock: 1.62GHz coreCount: 6 deviceMemorySize: 4.00GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 104.43GiB/s
2020-10-30 12:03:25.065861: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_101.dll
2020-10-30 12:03:25.066244: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library cublas64_10.dll
2020-10-30 12:03:25.066580: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library cufft64_10.dll
2020-10-30 12:03:25.066872: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library curand64_10.dll
2020-10-30 12:03:25.067182: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library cusolver64_10.dll
2020-10-30 12:03:25.067619: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library cusparse64_10.dll
2020-10-30 12:03:25.068034: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library cudnn64_7.dll
2020-10-30 12:03:25.068448: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1858] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2020-10-30 12:03:25.734018: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1257] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2020-10-30 12:03:25.734464: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1263]      0 
2020-10-30 12:03:25.734664: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1276] 0:   N 
2020-10-30 12:03:25.735009: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1402] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 2984 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 1050 Ti, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 6.1)
2020-10-30 12:03:25.738356: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:168] XLA service 0x1daa2f2ca40 initialized for platform CUDA (this does not guarantee that XLA will be used). Devices:
2020-10-30 12:03:25.738781: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:176]   StreamExecutor device (0): GeForce GTX 1050 Ti, Compute Capability 6.1
WARNING:tensorflow:From C:/Users/Lenovo/PycharmProjects/AI/1- Text.py:66: Model.fit_generator (from tensorflow.python.keras.engine.training) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Please use Model.fit, which supports generators.
Model: "sequential"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv2d (Conv2D)              (None, 997, 997, 32)      544       
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d (MaxPooling2D) (None, 332, 332, 32)      0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_1 (Conv2D)            (None, 329, 329, 64)      32832     
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_1 (MaxPooling2 (None, 109, 109, 64)      0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_2 (Conv2D)            (None, 106, 106, 64)      65600     
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_2 (MaxPooling2 (None, 35, 35, 64)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_3 (Conv2D)            (None, 32, 32, 128)       131200    
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_3 (MaxPooling2 (None, 10, 10, 128)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_4 (Conv2D)            (None, 7, 7, 128)         262272    
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_4 (MaxPooling2 (None, 2, 2, 128)         0         
_________________________________________________________________
flatten (Flatten)            (None, 512)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense (Dense)                (None, 256)               131328    
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 256)               65792     
_________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 1)                 257       
=================================================================
Total params: 689,825
Trainable params: 689,825
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
Epoch 1/30
2020-10-30 12:03:27.997615: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library cublas64_10.dll
2020-10-30 12:03:28.951268: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library cudnn64_7.dll
2020-10-30 12:03:29.803616: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:246] Allocator (GPU_0_bfc) ran out of memory trying to allocate 1.91GiB with freed_by_count=0. The caller indicates that this is not a failure, but may mean that there could be performance gains if more memory were available.
2020-10-30 12:03:29.804253: W tensorflow/core/kernels/gpu_utils.cc:49] Failed to allocate memory for convolution redzone checking; skipping this check. This is benign and only means that we won't check cudnn for out-of-bounds reads and writes. This message will only be printed once.
2020-10-30 12:03:29.805214: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1767] OP_REQUIRES failed at conv_ops.cc:1115 : Not found: No algorithm worked!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Lenovo/PycharmProjects/AI/1- Text.py", line 66, in <module>
    history = model_.fit_generator(
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\deprecation.py", line 324, in new_func
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 1815, in fit_generator
    return self.fit(
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 108, in _method_wrapper
    return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 1098, in fit
    tmp_logs = train_function(iterator)
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py", line 780, in __call__
    result = self._call(*args, **kwds)
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py", line 840, in _call
    return self._stateless_fn(*args, **kwds)
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py", line 2829, in __call__
    return graph_function._filtered_call(args, kwargs)  # pylint: disable=protected-access
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py", line 1843, in _filtered_call
    return self._call_flat(
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py", line 1923, in _call_flat
    return self._build_call_outputs(self._inference_function.call(
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py", line 545, in call
    outputs = execute.execute(
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\execute.py", line 59, in quick_execute
    tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError:  No algorithm worked!
     [[node sequential/conv2d/Conv2D (defined at /Users/Lenovo/PycharmProjects/AI/1- Text.py:66) ]] [Op:__inference_train_function_1397]

Function call stack:
train_function

2020-10-30 12:03:29.893708: W tensorflow/core/kernels/data/generator_dataset_op.cc:103] Error occurred when finalizing GeneratorDataset iterator: Failed precondition: Python interpreter state is not initialized. The process may be terminated.
     [[{{node PyFunc}}]]

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I search for that error but I didn't solve this. Is there any solution?

Comment: Seems like a Cuda issue. The error originates from [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v2.3.1/tensorflow/core/kernels/gpu_utils.cc#L251), in turn called from [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v2.3.1/tensorflow/core/kernels/conv_ops.cc#L1115). Check that Cuda is correctly installed with the right version. Also, [release 2.2.0](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/releases/tag/v2.2.0) mentions fixing an error like that in relation to the environment variables `TF_DETERMINSTIC_OPS` and `TF_CUDNN_DETERMINISTIC`...

Comment: As I said, I have used cuda before for detecting cats and dogs. And I had no problem. Are you sure about that ? Is this really about cuda version?

Comment: No, I'm not sure it is about the Cuda/Cudnn version, I'm just saying you may check your installation, or just reinstall it, and make sure the version is the right one for your TensorFlow version (e.g. if it is supposed to be 9.1, make sure it is not 9.0 or 9.2), just in case. What seems likely is that the issue is somehow related to Cuda/Cudnn, as that is what the source of the error suggests. You can also consider updating the GPU driver if you don't have the latest version, I have had some problems in the past that got fixed after that.

Comment: This issue probably because of GPU memory runs out of memory. Try setting memory_growth=True. Append the below snippet in your code and try.  `import tensorflow as tf                                                                                       
physical_devices = tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')
tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(physical_devices[0], True)`.

Answer (score 4):

This might not be the answer for the current context. Anyway, the same error can occur when the input shapes mismatch.  for an RGB image, there are 3 channels, 'R', 'G' and 'B' So, the input shape will be `(height, width, 3)`. If it is a grey scaled image the shape should be `(height, width, 1)`

```
model.add(Conv2D(
    32,
    (4, 4),
    activation='relu',
    input_shape=(1000, 1000, 1)
    )
)
```

Answer (score 2):

I experienced this problem on Ubuntu with tensorflow on GPU.

The cause of the issue was problem with the cuda libraries.

In my case, it was resolved by installing *nvidia-cuda-toolkit*.
In order to access these packages, you need the *nvidia repo.* in your *sources.list*:

```
sudo echo 'deb http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/machine-learning/repos/ubuntu1804/x86_64 /' >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nvidia-machine-learning.list
sudo apt update
```

Then install *nvidia-cuda-toolkit*:

```
# dependency required for nvidia-cuda-toolkit
sudo apt install nvidia-compute-utils-455
sudo apt install nvidia-cuda-toolkit
```